# Variable height of the list items

Tags: javascript, listview, datatemplate, multiline, webix

I'm trying to use Webix ui.list with multiline text data. Something like

```
webix.ui({  
  view:'list', 
  data: [
    { id:1, value:'A' }, 
    { id:2, value:'B<br>B' }, 
    { id:3, value:'C<br>C<br>' }    
  ],
  template: '#value#', 
});
```

[(snippet)](http://webix.com/snippet/efa6a6b7)

But I can't find any way to set the variable height for the list items. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add the "type" attribute of the "list" as **type:{ height:"auto"}** in your code, it will adjust the height of the list items based on their content size.

Comment: it falls to 1px ( ugh